# Call object function when said object contained in list

Tags: c++, class, iterator, abstract

Hello I am trying to call a print function of a class that is inherited from an abstract base class. The problem is that I need to call it from a list containing pointers of said abstract base class

e.g

```
list<abstract_base*> L
```

To traverse list I know I have to use iterators e.g

```
list<abstract_base*>:: it = L.begin ()
```

But know I don't know how to call the print function.

I've tried `*it->print()`

And a few other things nothing works I just get compiler errors.

This is in c++

Comment: A language tag would help to draw attention.

Comment: what's the compiler error?